# Animate item along SVG path

Tags: html, css, angular, svg

I am not very familiar in working with SVG and am trying to animate a `<path>` line:

The following is what I am trying to achieve

[image]

The orange circle at the end should run along the blue line, however I cannot figure out how to get the loop at the end of the line (the red block in the middle can be ignored, it is a custom icon).

so far I have the following:

```
<svg width="192" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle class="circle" cx="0" cy=0 r=7 stroke=#f70202 stroke-width=2 fill=#f92020 >
    <animateMotion dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto" >
      <mpath xlink:href="#path"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  <path id="path" d="M10 50 Q 95 150 180 120" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Here is codepen for the same: https://codepen.io/undert0w/pen/jOVVJMe

**How can I extend the blue line with a loop and have the orange circle follow the blue line?**

(ps. I am using Angular if it makes any difference)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg width="600" height="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle class="circle" cx="0" cy=0 r=7 stroke=#f70202 stroke-width=2 fill=#f92020 >
<animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto" >
    <mpath xlink:href="#path"/>
</animateMotion>
</circle>
<path id="path" d="M61,50c0,0,76,143,163,103S288-1,411,50s180,90,113,165s-203-16-207-53s163-99,154-30c0,0-14,55-30,55
    s-33.5-6.7-76-23s-29-87.1-76-23.6S224,229,177,213s-91,2-59-64s27-87,68-91s9,35,82,36s55,14,112-20S480-35,528,31s38,106,5,127
    s-43,50-27,62s45,19,45,19" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

The easiest way is to draw the line you want in Illustrator, then save it as SVG[image]

after that just click: SVG Code and take the code of path between d="...."

!!Remember!! to adjust the viewBox area

Here is a code that's done this way.

```
<svg width="600" height="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle class="circle" cx="0" cy=0 r=7 stroke=#f70202 stroke-width=2 fill=#f92020 >
<animateMotion dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto" >
    <mpath xlink:href="#path"/>
</animateMotion>
</circle>
<path id="path" d="M61,50c0,0,76,143,163,103S288-1,411,50s180,90,113,165s-203-16-207-53s163-99,154-30" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the question right. But if you are trying to create a loop path with the blue line.

Try creating the path in any svg editor and copy the source.

You can understand clearly from this recording.
**https://youtu.be/vjLCAMaBr4A**

[image]